# Define a function in Calc (Embedded)

Tags: calc

In Calc Embedded Mode, you can define a variable with the `:=` operator. You can then use it in an equation using the `=>` operator and it will be automatically updated when you change the variable. See [(calc) Assignments in Embedded Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Assignments-in-Embedded-Mode.html).

*Example:*

- Create a new buffer containing:

```
x := 3

x + 2 => 9999
```

- Invoke `calc-embedded-activate` (`C-x * a`)
- Invoke `calc-embedded-update-formula` (`C-x * u`) on the bottom equation. It changes to `x + 2 => 5`
- Now enter embedded mode on the top equation and change it to `x := 30`. The bottom one will change to `x + 2 => 32`.

But this doesn't work with functions. Create a buffer containing

```
f(x) := 2 x

f(2) => 9999
```

Invoke `C-x * a` anywhere and invoke `C-x * u` on the bottom equation. It changes to `f(2) => f(2)`. Changing the top equation doesn't affect the bottom one.

Is there any way to define a function from within Calc or does it have another way of dealing with this? I know of `defmath` but that doesn't help in e.g. a Latex document (unless you define the function twice, likely making mistakes).

Comment: Could you please describe which commands you use to make your first example working? I'm unable to imitate it to get the same output.

Comment: @jue I rewrote the question, hope it's clearer now

Comment: Your linked document states (at the bottom): `Assignments to other kinds of objects can be represented by Calc, but the automatic linkage between assignments and references works only for plain variables ...`.  So how to do the linkage for other objects? Maybe Omars answer shows this?

Answer (score 3):

This probably won't be very satisfying but you can use the anonymous function syntax and call the function with the `call` function:

```
f := <x : 2 x>

call(f, 7) => 14
```

(Sadly `f(7)` doesn't work.)